# Summing different dates and categories

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum, pandas-groupby

So I have a pandas data frame that is grouped by date and a particular category and has the sum of another column. What I would like to do is take the number for a particular category for a particular day and add it to the next day and then take that number and add it to the next day. For example, say the category is apples, the date is 5-26-2021 and the cost is $5. The next day, 5-27-2021 is $6. So 5-27-2021 should have a cost of $11. Then 5-28-2021 has a cost of $3 but it should be added to $11 so the cost should show up as $14. How can I go about doing this? There are multiple categories by the way besides just the apples. Thank you!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmV3D.png)
Expected Output:
(the output is not the most accurate and this data frame is not the most accurate so feel free to ask questions)

Comment: Can you add a sample of the dataframe and the expected output?

Comment: I added a very rough example. Basically, there will be multiple dates, for each date there will be multiple categories, for each category and date there will be a cost. I would like the output to basically give me a sum of the previous day added to the current day

Answer (score -1):

Use groupby then [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)

```py
data = [
    [2021, 'apple', 1,],
    [2022, 'apple', 2,],
    [2021, 'banana', 3,],
    [2022, 'cherry', 4],
    [2022, 'banana', 5],
    [2023, 'cherry', 6],
]
columns = ['date','category', 'cost']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
>>> df
   date category  cost
0  2021    apple     1
1  2022    apple     2
2  2021   banana     3
3  2022   cherry     4
4  2022   banana     5
5  2023   cherry     6
```

```py
df.sort_values(['category','date'], inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df['CostCsum'] = df.groupby(['category'])['cost'].cumsum()
```

```
   date category  cost  CostCsum
0  2021    apple     1         1
1  2022    apple     2         3
2  2021   banana     3         3
3  2022   banana     5         8
4  2022   cherry     4         4
5  2023   cherry     6        10
```

Comment: I was wrong, it did work, thank you so much!